# How to find the value of this giant?

Tags: number-theory

How can I find the value of this giant exponent: "2 raised to the power of 1717986918400"? Should one need a supercomputer to calculate this number? Is there any theory in math that can specify how many digits would this value have?

Comment: Do you know logarithms?  You should be able to calculate the base 10 logarithm of the answer easily.  Prior to calculators, problems like this were one of the reasons that base 10 logarithms were popular.  I am old enough to have $\log_{10}(2) = 0.30103$ burned into my brain.

Comment: Since $2^{10}$ is about $10^3$, you can divide your exponent by $3$ and get an estimate for the number of digits.  About $(1/2)\times 10^{12}.$

Comment: Often times, one doesn't need the full value...sometimes just knowing it $\pmod p$ for some prime (or primes) $p$ is good enough.  That's a lot easier than writing the whole thing out.

Comment: @lulu A good point.  You can get the first few digits via the logarithm and the last few by modulus techniques.  It is the mere few hundred billion in the middle that are tricky.

Comment: Since computers often use binary arithmetic, for them the task to compute your numbers is almost trivial; the real work is to generate a decimal representation.

Comment: @gammatester A good point.  The binary representation of this number is quite simple.  One followed by $1717986918400$ zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This number has

$$\left\lfloor1717986918400\frac{\log2}{\log10}\right\rfloor+1=517165594597$$ digits.

Written in ASCII code, this takes half a terabyte and doesn't fit in the memory of a PC.

Using a bignum library able to swap to disk, I would expect a few hours of work.